# remove a code line begining with username in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to create a regex to select all lines begining with 'username'=> and remove them.

I began my regex, but I'm a little bit stuck :

This code selects any lines begining with username :

```
(?<='username'=>)
```

**but I wondering how can I select the end of the line too and remove it ?**

This is an example :

```
'username'=> 'CRPV',
```

I'm working with Visual Studio Code.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Add a piece of the file you use. Does `'username'` start at the beginning of the line or is there white space?

Answer (score 0):

**Find:**

Enable button `.*` in Find dialog

```
^'username'.*\n?
```

**Replace:** with nothing.

The `?` at the end is if the last line without a newline character is also a `username` line

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply.  Weird, it seems that it does not work.  I have no result...

Comment: @laravelnoobie Do you enable the regex Find? Enable button `.*` in Find dialog

Comment: yes, this is the liink to show you https://www.dropbox.com/s/pbo4upcuqx3eudi/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202020-07-16%2010.03.20.png?dl=0